# Optimizing nested if statements in switch

Tags: c#, performance

I have this code and I think it is very slow, about 50ms. I need to make it execute faster:

```
 switch (unit)
   {
       case 0:
       if (u == 2)
       {
           if (u1 == "piece" || u1 == "gram")
               result = quantity * y;
           else
               result = quantity * z;
       }
       if (u == 1)
       {
           if (u1 == "piece" || u1 == "gram")
               result = quantity * y;
           else
               result = quantity;
       }
       res_name = "gram";
       break;

       case 1: //ml
       if (u == 2)
       {
           if (u1 == "piece" || u1 == "gram")
               result = quantity * x;
           else
               result = quantity * y;

       }
       if (u == 0)
       {
           if (u1 == "piece" || u1 == "gram")
               result  = quantity * x;
           else
               result = quantity;
       }
       res_u = "ml";
       break;

case 2:
    res_u = "pieces";
    break;
 }
```

Comment: Can you give more information about unit, u, u1, res_u, result, quantity, x, y, z?

Comment: @Romoku x, y, and z are fields I get from db. result and res_u are the fields I return from the method.

Comment: I more or less meant what are their object types?

Comment: @Srcee, please describe the meaning of parameters and their values. What the it mean when `unit` is equal to `0`, `1` and `2`? Are these the only values it can have? What is the logical meaning of `u`, and what does the values `0`, `1` and `2` mean? Basically your code suffers from well-known [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) problem

Comment: @Srcee as to your statement `I think it is very slow, about 50ms. I need to make it execute faster` - that is not the case, this code will perform much faster unless you're running it on 20 Mhz computer ;). Most likely the slow part is the data retrieval. Please describe how exactly you've measured the performance

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [Romoku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/21332/romoku).  Unless there is a definite requirement to make this faster and a noticeable effect on performance of your application within this method I would consider making it more DRY, more developer friendly and less procedural.

Without more code and explanation of whats there here are some things I would consider:

1. Try and remove duplicated code.  I notice you repeat your `if(u1 == "piece"` ... code everywhere.  Consider moving that into a method and passing in the parameters required.

   ```
   private int GetConversion(UnitsEnum units, int pieceGramsMultipler, int otherMultipler)
   {
     return units == UnitsEnum.Piece || units == UnitsEnum.Gram
                    ? pieceGramsMultipler
                    : otherMultipler;               
   }
   ```

   Then used like

   ```
   if (u == 2)
   {
      result = quantity * GetConversion(u1, y, z);                        
   }
   ```
2. Consider changing your string literals into enumerations. So "piece" and "gram" might become:

   ```
   private enum UnitsEnum
   {
     Piece,
     Gram
   }
   ```
3. Consider changing your case statements into constants or enumerations.  So rather than case 1, it might be case `Metric.Ml` or `ML` or `Milliliters` etc
4. Offer better names for your variables.  u1, x, y, z gives me no idea of what they are trying to do.
5. Use if else instead of 2 if statements.  If u == 2 then there is no chance that it will be == 1 so convert your if's into if elses to make that more obvious.

Otherwise, perhaps posting the full code that this piece resides in might get your more help and suggestions.  I get the feeling that there is more help this community can offer you here than just what you have posted.

Comment: Very good advice in this post; just one minor quibble: `UnitsEnum` should probably be called `Unit`, I don't see a reason to encode the type in the name. In fact, the enums may be unnecessary if the raw integer values can be replaced with domain types — but your answer is still the best one possible given the limited information in the question.

Comment: @codesparkle Good points. I don't even know if even Unit is the best name.  Took a wild guess there :)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would do is refactor your names to something understandable. After that I would try to create a data structure to encapsulate the nested logic.

Without knowing more about the background it is hard to refactor without breaking some kind of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than guessing which lines *might* be the ones taking up a lot of CPU time, you should run this code through a profiler, which will tell you which parts take up most of the run-time, which are the parts you should then target for optimization.

Comment: I get the 50ms time with profiler.

Comment: Which profiler are you using?

Comment: This one: http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: It looks like miniprofiler has a `step` function you can use to narrow down how long specific pieces of code take.

Alternatively, you could time parts of your code manually with the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class.

Answer (score 2):

dreza is correct that you could split some of your code up into functions.

Many parts of it can be combined into smaller sections:

```
if (u == 2)
{
    if (u1 == "piece" || u1 == "gram")
        result = quantity * y;
    else
        result = quantity * z;
}
if (u == 1)
{
    if (u1 == "piece" || u1 == "gram")
        result = quantity * y;
    else
        result = quantity;
}
```

I would write this instead:

```
if (u == 1 || u == 2)
{
    if (u1 == "piece" || u1 == "gram")
    {
        result = quantity * y;
    }
    else
    {
        result = u == 1 ? quantity : quantity * z;

        // This also works the same way:
        // result = quantity * (u == 1 ? 1 : z);
    }
}
```

This makes fewer (by half) the lines of code to maintain, not counting braces.  Also, notice how I put braces around my code to help prevent errors.

Romoku also make very good points about renaming your variables to reflect what they are doing better.